# uwp textbox header visible only when text length is more than 0

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, textbox, styles

I am trying to edit the style of default textbox is such a way that whenever it has text the header should be visible and when it is empty the placeholder shows up and header goes away. The thing is I have to do this within style and without creating a custom control or user control, that's why it's a bit tricky for me.

I was able to put a border around whole control (including header) but I am so far unable to control visibility of the header. I've put the style in a separate project, Following is the code.

**TextBox Properties class**

```
public class TextBoxProperties : DependencyObject
{
    public static bool GetInitialized(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue(InitializedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInitialized(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InitializedProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Initialized.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InitializedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Initialized", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxProperties), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnInitialized));

    private static void OnInitialized(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox) d;
        tb.TextChanged += Tb_TextChanged;
        Update(tb);
    }

    private static void Tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Update((TextBox)sender);
    }

    private static void Update(TextBox tb) => SetShouldHeaderBeVisible(tb, tb.Text.Length > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed);

    public static Visibility GetShouldHeaderBeVisible(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Visibility) obj.GetValue(ShouldHeaderBeVisibleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetShouldHeaderBeVisible(DependencyObject obj, Visibility value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ShouldHeaderBeVisibleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShouldHeaderBeVisible.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShouldHeaderBeVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShouldHeaderBeVisible", typeof(Visibility), typeof(TextBoxProperties), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

**TextBox Style**

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="local:TextBoxProperties.Initialized" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Grid
                                                    x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                    Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                    <TextBlock
                                                        x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                        FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                        FontSize="12"
                                                        FontStyle="Normal"
                                                        Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}"
                                                        Text="&#xE10A;" />
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                        To="0"
                                                                        Duration="0" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border
                                x:Name="BorderElement"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" />
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="{StaticResource InputHeaderMargin}"
                                x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                FontWeight="Normal"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
                                TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                                Visibility="{Binding local:TextBoxProperties.ShouldHeaderBeVisibleProperty, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            <ScrollViewer
                                x:Name="ContentElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
                                TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" />
                            <Button
                                x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                MinWidth="34"
                                Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>

                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: I made a simple test. After adding the style and the class, the TextBox won't show the header whether it has text or not. But this is a conflict with your title which said the header won't show when there is no text. So is this the issue you said?

Comment: yes that is the issue bcz of the attempted fix I messed up the header actually

Comment: Quick reminder touseefbsb - please install and use an English spell-checker here. That would cut down the amount of editing work required - posts here are for the loing term and we want them to be as correct and readable as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably attempt to apply binding directly to HeaderContentPresenter.Visibility won't succeed since the property is programatically controlled by TextBox. So, put the HeaderContentPresenter in another Border and change its Visibility.

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="{TemplateBinding local:TextBoxProperties.ShouldHeaderBeVisible}">
    <ContentPresenter
        x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
        Margin="{StaticResource InputHeaderMargin}"
        x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
        FontWeight="Normal"
        Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
        TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Border>
```